# Detecting user ended touching screen

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, touch-event

in my app i'm able to detect a touch by connecting the view to an action touch down event. However, i want to be able to detect that the user lifted his finger off screen. am i able to do that?

Edit: sorry for the short post. actually i have no hint how to do that or even to try to do that!

Comment: This touches, usually come in pairs, if you have touch down then you definitely have touch up. Give a try on google ;)

Comment: there is a touch up outside and touchup inside. i tried the outside and it didn't work.

Comment: I'm not familiar with iOS, but does [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/multitouch_background/multitouch_background.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH5-SW9) help at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that depends on where you're trying to track the touch removal. If for example, you're using a button and you've already linked an action to touchDown, you can simply link another action for the buttons control event touch up inside/outside.

If you're interested in tracking that touches ended on the entire screen, you can use `-touchesEnded: withEvent:`.

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: thanks. i tried touch up outside and it's working. i'm using it on the view which is of UIControl class.